# Changing out my ceiling fan i got four white and four black wiresand cant tell which should be tied together

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

After taking down my old ceiling fan I have four white and four black. 3 white was together as well as black. One white and one black was connected, but I sepererated all and don't know which black and white go together.
I know a black is hot but which white do I connect it with (hot)?

Comment: Why did you separate them? Can you take a picture of the fan box?  Do you know where the other wires in the box go to,  what is out when you turned off the breaker?

Comment: Is there a bit of black tape on one of the white wires?

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: What you likely have is a [standard switch loop](https://blog.smartthings.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/74e10558f0701a863ad0f7569cb3edbdaadf0ae3.png). You'll need to determine which cable makes the run to the switch and connect it like that. All others are color-to-color.